# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

```
int num;
int num2;

Console.Write("insert one number: ");
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("insert another number: ");
num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int Result =  Console.WriteLine(Math.Pow (num, 2));

int result =  Console.WriteLine(Math.Pow (num2, 2));



Console.Write("the square roots of the given numbers are: "+ num +", "+ num2 + "and the greatest number is: ");

Console.ReadKey();
```

the interface of the new vs code studio is exactly like how i wrote here, there seems to be no main function so am confused while checking old solutions from others

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` does not return a value.

Comment: [`public static void WriteLine (...);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-8.0) - Note the **`void`** part.

Comment: remove `int Result =` and `int result =` it will work

Comment: It's extremely bad practice to name two variables Result and result. You are asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want in `Result` and `result` are the results of `Math.Pow (num, 2)` and `Math.Pow (num2, 2)` but instead your code is trying to store the results of the console writes - this will not work since the results is `void` not an `int`.

Instead store the results first and then do the console writes.

```
int result = Math.Pow (num, 2);
int result2 = Math.Pow (num2, 2); 
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

Note: I've renamed the "result" variables for readability.

Answer (score 2):

In order for you to be able to assign the return type of a method to a variable then that method needs to have a return type. `Console.WriteLine()`  does not have a return type, that is why the compiler generated the error your saw.

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine is void and doesn't return a result.if you want to return a data and full this variable Result ,you must use this code

```
double Result = Math.Pow(num, 2);
Console.WriteLine(Result);
double Result2 = Math.Pow(num2, 2);

Console.WriteLine(Result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this part of code.

`int Result =  Console.WriteLine(Math.Pow (num, 2));`

Happening because Console.WriteLine return type is `void` not `int`.

You need to change it like

```
int Result = Math.Pow(num,2);
Console.WriteLine(Result);
```